# Spark find consecutive timeframes

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to find continues timestamps in a really big dataset. This needs to be done in Spark using Java (code examples in Scala are also very welcome).

Each row looks like the following:

ID, startTime, endTime

For example the dataset:

`[[1, 10, 15],[1, 15, 20], [2, 10, 13], [1, 22, 33], [2, 13, 16]]`

The expected outcome are all continous time frames for the same id, with for each continous time frame only the start and ending time:

`[[1, 10, 20],[1, 22, 33], [2, 10, 16]]`

I already tried the following, but that doesn't work out because the order is not maintained. Thereby I would expect that there is a more efficient way to do this

```
textFile.mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<>(x[0],new Tuple2<>(x[1], x[2])
    .mapValues(x -> new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(x)))
    .reduceByKey((x,y) -> {
         Tuple2<Long, Long> v1 = x.getLast();
         Tuple2<Long, Long> v2 = y.getFirst();
         Tuple2<Long, Long> v3 = v2;
         if(v2._1().equals(v1._2())) {
              v3 = new Tuple2<>(v1._1(), v2._2());
              x.removeLast();
         }
         x.addLast(v3);
         return x;
    })
    .flatMapValues(x -> x);
```

Comment: You can sort surely? Other approaches will have same issue possibly.

Comment: But this doens"t look like a good approach to me, the amount of IDS is very limited, while the amount of time frames for each ID is very big, so using this method a lot of long computations will run on the same node

Comment: The reduce funtion even requires the function to be comutative and associative, which is not the case here

Comment: Still suggest ordering

Comment: Everybody talks about commutative and associative. That's ok for word count and such. Here you simple need everything on 1 partition so as to avoid shuffling.

Comment: The answer has the same parallel assumptions as I have.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a Spark problem, but the logical one.
You should consider the option of using several standalone functions:

- to bind two intervals together (let's name it `bindEntries()`)
- to add new interval into the interval accumulator of intervals (let it be `insertEntry()`)

Suggesting, we have mock data `mockData`:

```
+---+-----+---+
| id|start|end|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|   22| 33|
|  1|   15| 20|
|  1|   10| 15|
|  2|   13| 16|
|  2|   10| 13|
+---+-----+---+
```

With the help of these functions, my solution to your problem will be like this:

```scala
val processed = mockData
      .groupByKey(_.id)
      .flatMapGroups { (id: Int, it: Iterator[Entry]) =>
        processEntries(it)
      }
```

The only goal of `processEntries()` is to fold all the entries for each id into the collection of non-intersecting intervals. 
Here is it's signature:

```scala
def processEntries(it: Iterator[Entry]): List[Entry] =
    it.foldLeft(Nil: List[Entry])(insertEntry)
```

This function is used to get elements from your grouped entries one by one and push them into the accumulator, one by one as well.

Function `insertEntry()` handling this kind of insertion:

```scala
def insertEntry(acc: List[Entry], e: Entry): List[Entry] = acc match {
  case Nil => e :: Nil
  case a :: as =>
    val combined = bindEntries(a, e)
    combined match {
      case x :: y :: Nil => x :: insertEntry(as, y)
      case x :: Nil => insertEntry(as, x)
      case _ => a :: as
    }
}
```

The `bindEntries()` function should handle the order of entries for you:

```scala
def bindEntries(x: Entry, y: Entry): List[Entry] =
  (x.start > y.end, x.end < y.start) match {
    case (true, _) => y :: x :: Nil
    case (_, true) => x :: y :: Nil
    case _ => x.copy(start = x.start min y.start, end = x.end max y.end) :: Nil
  }
```

`bindEntries()` will return the list of one or two entries **properly sorted**.
This is the idea behind it:

[image]

`insertEntry()` will sort all the entries for you during insertion.

After all, the resulting dataset looks like this:

```
+---+-----+---+
| id|start|end|
+---+-----+---+
|  1|   10| 20|
|  1|   22| 33|
|  2|   10| 16|
+---+-----+---+
```

**Note:** Function `insertEntry()` is not tail-recursive. 
There is a good starting point for further optimisations.

And there is the complete solution:

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoder, Encoders, SparkSession}

object AdHoc {

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val processed = mockData
      .groupByKey(_.id)
      .flatMapGroups { (id, it) =>
        processEntries(it)
      }

    mockData.show()
    processed.show()
  }


  def processEntries(it: Iterator[Entry]): List[Entry] =
    it.foldLeft(Nil: List[Entry])(insertEntry)

  def insertEntry(acc: List[Entry], e: Entry): List[Entry] = acc match {
    case Nil => e :: Nil
    case a :: as =>
      val combined = bindEntries(a, e)
      combined match {
        case x :: y :: Nil => x :: insertEntry(as, y)
        case x :: Nil => insertEntry(as, x)
        case _ => a :: as
      }
  }

  def bindEntries(x: Entry, y: Entry): List[Entry] =
    (x.start > y.end, x.end < y.start) match {
      case (true, _) => y :: x :: Nil
      case (_, true) => x :: y :: Nil
      case _ => x.copy(start = x.start min y.start, end = x.end max y.end) :: Nil
    }

  lazy val mockData: Dataset[Entry] = spark.createDataset(Seq(
    Entry(1, 22, 33),
    Entry(1, 15, 20),
    Entry(1, 10, 15),
    Entry(2, 13, 16),
    Entry(2, 10, 13)
  ))

  case class Entry(id: Int, start: Int, end: Int)

  implicit lazy val entryEncoder: Encoder[Entry] = Encoders.product[Entry]

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()
}
```

Comment: I would have solved this with SQL approach, so I like to see an alternative. Good stuff.

Comment: On holidays. Have done similar things before on SO, but more SQL. OK, I see how it is done. The questioner was concerned with few IDs, but I see you think like I do in that regard. I see no need to post an alternative, provided this works functionally.